# Right justify number including prefix using printf

Tags: c++, printf

How do I output a number using the HEX prefix '0x' with one `printf` statement and be right justified?

For example if I try to right justify with 10 characters but the number is less than 10 characters like this:

```
printf("0x%10X\n", number);
```

Output:

[image]

---

I want it to look like this (ignore the fact that the picture has a different number in it):

[image]

---

I've tried a few variations of the above code and this is the closest one I've found so far.

Comment: Would you be OK with `0x0035800000`?

Comment: You use the `0` modifier to specify that the padding should be zeroes instead of spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `#` modifier, which makes the `0x` prefix part of the field.

```
printf("%#10x\n", number)
```

Comment: That worked for my needs.  I hadn't figured out that option yet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using C++ I/O stream modifiers work just as well (it's safer too):

```
unsigned int short_hexidecimal_value = 0xff; //Less than ten characters in hex.
unsigned long long long_hexidecimal_value = 0xfabcdef987; //Ten or more characters in hex.
std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::right << std::uppercase << std::hex << "0x" << short_hexidecimal_value << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(20) << "0x" << long_hexidecimal_value  << '\n';
```